# Disable Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm in a selection process and I must develop a software in Django with the restriction of not being able to use the admin included in the framework.

I tried removing it from the INSTALLED_APPS. But when I run a migration I get the error:

```
'No installed app with label 'admin'
```

Is there any other configuration that I should do or what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: have you removed it from the url patterns? not sure it'll remove the error, but at least it will be impossible to reach any view from the admin site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to remove it from:

- urls.py

  - remove from `urlpatterns`
  - remove the import statement
- INSTALLED_APPS

That's it.